# How can a positive integrand integrate to 0?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, logarithms, residue-calculus, singularity-theory

I integrated $\dfrac{\log x}{1+x^2}$ from $0$ to infinity with residue calculus and got... $0$.

This also agrees with Wolfram Alpha.

How can this be?

Is it due to the behavior of $\log(x)$ near the origin?  Like a cancellation effect?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you say it's a positive integrand when it isn't?

Comment: for x<1 your function is not positive

Comment: O gee...thanks so much @mattsamuel ...

Comment: Got it - thanks @math635,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the substitution $u=\frac{1}{x}$ you get

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\log x}{1+x^2} \, dx =\int_1^\infty \frac{\log(\frac{1}{x})}{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \, dx=\int_1^0 \frac{\log u}{1+u^2} \, du =-\int_0^1 \frac{\log u}{1+u^2} \, du $$

Yes, the two integrals cancel out.

If you calculate your integral the same way, you get that it is equal to minus itself...

Comment: +1.  However, I would add this comment: The integral $$ \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \, dx \right) \,dy $$ is clearly equal to minus the integral $$ \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \, dy \right) \,dx, $$ but before we conclude that that means this integral is minus itself, and therefore $0$, one my plod through the computations and find that one of these is $\pi/4$ and the other is $-\pi/4$ (or is it $\pi/2$ and $-\pi/2$?).  This is possible because the integral of the absolute value of this function is $+\infty$.  So before$\,\ldots\,\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$before we say that since it's minus itself, it must be $0$, one should check that the integral of the absolute value is finite. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, I know, but I think it is pretty clear that $\int_1 ^ \infty $ is convergent ;)

Answer (score 3):

Recall that $\log x<0$ if $0<x<1$ and $\log x>0$ if $1<x$, so this is not a "positive integrand".